# Set WebDriver in a pageObject class and then call it in your testcase

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Can I write a method for WebDriver in a pageObject class, and then call the method in my testcase class?

```
public class setupMethods {

static WebDriver driver;

public static void setup(String browser) throws Exception{
    //Check if parameter passed from TestNG is 'firefox'
    if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){
    //create firefox instance
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "U:\\path\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    //Check if parameter passed as 'chrome'
    else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "U:\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    //Check if parameter passed as 'Edge'
            else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("IE")){
                System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","U:\\path\\IEDriverServer.exe");
                InternetExplorerDriver driver;
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            }
    else{
        //If no browser passed throw exception
        throw new Exception("Browser is not correct");
    }
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

}

This is a method that I would like to call in my test case class, but when I run the test it starts Chrome (or any other browser), but then returns `java.lang.NullPointerException` when it comes to the line of code where the driver needs to maximize the window `driver.manage().window().maximize();`

Comment: You have local and class level `WebDriver` declarations, take a look at @Mikhail's answer. In short, `Webdriver driver = new FirefoxDriver()` should be `driver = new FirefoxDriver()` since you already declared `driver` on the class level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Answering straight, **Yes**, `you can write a method for WebDriver in a pageObject class, and then call the method in your testcase class`

You need to consider certain changes in your code as follows:

1. As you need to `call the method in my testcase` you need to get back the `WebDriver` instance as a return. So change the method from `public static void setup(String browser)` to `public static WebDriver setup(String browser)`
2. As you have already declared the instance of the `WebDriver` as in `static WebDriver driver;`, so you no more need to mention the Class name `WebDriver` again while initializing the `driver` as in `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`

**Functionally, this is causing you `NullPointerException` in your code.**

3. There is no best practice but I would prefer to check the passed parameter `String browser` in `if` loops only.
4. Once you have completed all the actions within this class, return the `WebDriver` instance.
5. Your own code with some simple tweaks will look like:

   ```
   public class setupMethods 
   {

       static WebDriver driver;

       public static void setup(String browser) throws Exception
       {
           //Check if parameter passed from TestNG is 'firefox'
           if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox"))
           {
               //create firefox instance
               System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "U:\\path\\geckodriver.exe");
               driver = new FirefoxDriver();
           }

           //Check if parameter passed as 'chrome'
           if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
           {
               System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "U:\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
               driver = new ChromeDriver();
           }

           //Check if parameter passed as 'Edge'
           if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("IE"))
           {
               System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","U:\\path\\IEDriverServer.exe");
               InternetExplorerDriver driver;
               driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
           }

           else
           {
               //If no browser passed throw exception
               throw new Exception("Browser is not correct");
           }

           driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
           return driver;
       }
   }
   ```

   Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the explanation. This works.....How should I initialize driver in other page object classes, or in test case classes? My test now runs, but when it comes to 'driver.manage().window().maximize();' it throws exception since it doesn`t know what the driver is, I guess. I am new to Java.

Answer (score 2):

You're having local variable `driver` in your method, that's why you're getting this exception.
Remove type declaration for `driver` in method body.

Comment: Thanks, this works. How should I call the driver in other pageObject classes , and in testcase classes? 
I am currently doing it by defining a driver in testcase class, and then in each pageObject class there is a constructor for the driver. But I don`t know what needs to be changed in order for it to work as I described up there? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue that I had...after using code that @debanjanB suggested, and using constructor for a driver in page object classes by using

```
public name_of_pageobject_class(WebDriver driver){ 

    this.driver = setupMethods.driver; 

    }
```

and calling driver in test cases classes as:

```
WebDriver driver = setupMethods.setup("chrome");
```

Please correct me if anything might be wrong....but this now works.